# :nth-of-type or similar with ngFor

Tags: angular, sass

With an ngFor Ive made a loop that shows the content of an array in different colored boxes (div). In total there are 6 positions of the array (sometimes less than 6), and I want those six boxes in different background colors (a gradient of orange). I have tried with :nth-of-type(1),(2)... but they all adopt the same color, because they all end up identifying as .class-div:nth-of-type(1)

Is there a smarter way to do something like this in Angular 11?

Comment: Haven't tried this. But I'd take a look at sass list.nth instead... https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists ... then have a list of colours.. an a value in range say of 0 thru 5 for the 6 colours using mod maths.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely target the div's with :nth-of-type in your css file.

```
.my-class:nth-of-type(1) {
   background: red;
}
```

OR

You can add the index of the loop to the class thereby making it unique and then define in css.

```
*ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;" ngClass="item-{{i}}"

.item-2 {
   background: blue;
}
```

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i6unne?file=src/app/app.component.ts